# Hi, i'm trying to find an object inside of an object that isn't empty

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my current code, in my eyes it should find the object called margins, check the size and if it's greater than 0 it will print it into the console, but it can't seem to get it to work, can anyone help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly?

This is my code in python, the data structure is the object "margins" can contain an object with a stock object in it. if i do `mongoReturn = collection.find({"margins": {}})` it will display all of the empty documents in the collection but if I try to do what I try below it won't find any.

```
mongoReturn = collection.find({"margins": {"$size": {"$gt": 0}}})
for object in mongoReturn:
   print(object)
```

```
ID 
margins: Object 
  |__ MSFT: Object 

ID 
margins: Object 
  |__EMPTY
```

What I'm trying to do is to see if the margins object is empty, if it's not I want to include it in my list if this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$nor": [
    {
      margins: {
        $eq: {}
      }
    },
    {
      margins: {
        $eq: null
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GNumdxX9xsr)

Comment: for objects instead of arrays i'd need to replace the [] with {} right?
so for my example it would be

collection.find({"$expr": {"$gt": {{"$size": "$margins"}, 0}}}) in python

Comment: No it's as to be a list. It will return True if the first element of the list is greater than the second. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/)

Comment: Ahh sorry, i think i'm being misunderstood, i'll show you what my data structure looks like and try to explain it in more detail. 
ID
margins: Object
     |__ MSFT: Object

ID 
margins: Object
     |__EMPTY
What I'm trying to do is to see if the margins object is empty, if it's not I want to include it in my list if this makes sense? I've edited my main post to elabotate

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer. Hope I've understood correctly this time